# AJAX returns whole html - how can i return just one value?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

(edited after first messed up version)

My AJAX is returning my header.php page.I just want it to return the $result value 0 or 1.
I am using ajax to call my generateTicket.php. There i want to generateTickets, if there currently is no other ticket. If the generation was successful it should return 1, if not 0.

But currenty it is returing my header.php with my response (0 or 1) at the end. How can i prevent it from returning header.php.

AJAX:

```
function generateTicket() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'generateTicket.php',
    type: 'post',
    datatype: "json",
    data: {
      showid: <?php echo $showid ?>,
      seats: <?php echo $seats_json ?>
    },
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);  
    }
  });
}
```

generateTicket.php:

```
<?php 
include('includes/header.php');

//Login prüfen
if (!$loggedIn) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}

//Variablen init
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$showid = $_POST['showid'];
$seats = $_POST['seats'];
$result = 1;

//Für jeden Sitzplatz ein Ticket generien generieren
foreach($seats as $seat){
    //Datenbank Ticket laden
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  ticket_uebersicht WHERE Sitzplatz LIKE ? AND VorstellungID = ? LIMIT 1";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array($seat, $showid));
    $row = $statement->fetch();

    //Prüfen ob Ticket exestiert. Wenn ja -> Marktplatzticket -> anpassen. Wenn nein -> Neues Ticket generieren
    if(!$row){
        $code = guidv4();
        $query = "INSERT INTO tickets (code, UserID, VorstellungID, Sitzplatz) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(array($code, $userid, $showid, $seat));
        continue;
    }else{
        if($row['marktplatz'] != 0){
            $code = guidv4();
            $marketplace = '0';
            $query = "UPDATE tickets SET UserID = ?, code = ?, marktplatz = ? WHERE Sitzplatz = ? AND VorstellungID = ? AND NOT marktplatz = 0 LIMIT 1";
            $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(array($userid, $code, $marketplace, $seat,  $showid));
            
            if(!($row['UserID'] == -1)){
                $betrag = $row['preis'] - 2;
                $query = "INSERT INTO rueckerstattung (UserID, Betrag) VALUES (?,?)";
                $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute(array($row['UserID'], $betrag));
            }
            continue;
        }
        $result =  0; //Fehler
    }
    
}

echo json_encode($result);

//Generieren der Ticket ID (FREMDCODE)
function guidv4($data = null) {
    // Generate 16 bytes (128 bits) of random data or use the data passed into the function.
    $data = $data ?? random_bytes(16);
    assert(strlen($data) == 16);

    // Set version to 0100
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40);
    // Set bits 6-7 to 10
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);

    // Output the 36 character UUID.
    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
exit;
?>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
include('db_connect.php');
include('righthandler.php')
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>DHBW Kino Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Insert Favicon to make it show in Tab -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Schriftart -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Table Pack -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.2/locale/bootstrap-table-de-DE.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <!-- Titel/ Header der Website-->
  <div class="jumbotron container text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
      <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png"  width="60%">
  </div>
    
  <!-- Navigationsleiste -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" >
    <div class="container col-md-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-warning" href="../index.php">DHBW Kino</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Startseite</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../anfahrt.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Anfahrt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../info.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Über uns</a>
          </li>
          <?php if($loggedIn) { ?> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../tickets.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Tickets</a> </li> <?php } ?>
          <?php if(hasRight('CONTROL_PANEL')) { ?> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../controlpanel.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Verwaltung</a> </li> <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <?php if($loggedIn) { ?> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../profile.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Profil</a> </li> <?php } ?>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <?php
            if($loggedIn) {
              ?>
                <a class="nav-link" href="../logout.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Log Out</a>
              <?php
            } else {
              ?>
                <a class="nav-link" href="../login.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Log In</a>
              <?php
            }
            ?>
          </li>    
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </nav>
```

AJAX success response: (my index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>DHBW Kino Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Insert Favicon to make it show in Tab -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Schriftart -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Table Pack -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.2/locale/bootstrap-table-de-DE.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <!-- Titel/ Header der Website-->
  <div class="jumbotron container text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
      <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png"  width="60%">
  </div>
    
  <!-- Navigationsleiste -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" >
    <div class="container col-md-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-warning" href="../index.php">DHBW Kino</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Startseite</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../anfahrt.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Anfahrt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../info.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Über uns</a>
          </li>
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../tickets.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Tickets</a> </li>            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../controlpanel.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Verwaltung</a> </li>         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
           <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../profile.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Profil</a> </li>           <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="../logout.php" style="color: #D3D3D3">Log Out</a>
                        </li>    
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </nav>
1
```

Comment: If that's truly your code, then no one has set $loggedIn.  It's going to evaluate to 0 and reroute you back to login.php.

Comment: Ohh i messed up while copying. I will edit again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: generateTicket.php will need to be in the same directory as whatever request generated the AJAX request.  Are you sure that's the case?

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! The AJAX request is in the same folder as generateTicket.php

Comment: What is the purpose of including the header in a script that serves as an AJAX target?

Comment: you can resolve it if you include the header only if HTTP method is GET.  And include the code back ajax if HTTP method is POST

Comment: @El_Vanja First thank you for taking time to help me. I have a permission handler included in my header. There is also the permisson handler with $loggedIn set. But you are right, directly importing my db_connect.php and permission handler helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of your `index.php` is in the file `header.php`. Because you include `header.php` in the `generateTicket.php` file, you get the body of `index.php` in your ajax request. You can imagine that the `include` expression more or less just replaces itself with the content of the included file.

You have to move the HTML code from `header.php` to some other file, or do not include the `header.php` file in `generateTicket.php`.

However, if neither of the options is suitable for you, there is a workaround. You can buffer the output from `header.php` and then just drop it.

```php
ob_start();
include('includes/header.php');
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Both ways (buffer and import without html) worked for me! Thank you so much, really helped me!